# Execute task with quartz in a java project

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I want to execute a task every Monday at 9am, so I'm using Quartz but I'm having some problems with the implementation in my Java project. I've seen some tuto on the web but none of them were useful for me. Here is what I have done :

**quartz.properties**

```
# Configuring Main Scheduler Properties
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = TriggerQuartz
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = 1
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export = false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy = false

# Configuring ThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 30
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5

org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class=org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin
```

**TriggerQuartz.java**

```
package servlet;
import org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import org.quartz.TriggerBuilder;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

public class TriggerQuartz 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {       
        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(DHTask.class)
        .withIdentity("dummyJobName", "group1").build();

        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
        .newTrigger()
        .withIdentity("dummyTriggerName", "group1")
        .withSchedule(
            CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("  0 0 9 ? * MON *"))
        .build();


        Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

    }
}
```

**DHTask.java**

```
package servlet;
import org.quartz.*;

public class DHTask implements Job
{
    DHData data = new DHData();
    DHDemande d = new DHDemande();
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
    throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("Task done!");
    }
}
```

What did I missed ?

Comment: Do you get an error / exception? Or is it just not triggering?

Comment: @Fildor No error and no exception, this is just not triggering